# Perl XML::SAX partial parsing

Tags: xml, windows, perl, xml-parsing, sax

Is it possible to pause and resume parsing using a handler class for `XML::SAX::Expat`?

The file is very large, we are reading nodes into memory to render a table. We want to only render one section at a time or we run out of memory. So we need to stop parsing the file, do some things in other parts of the program, then resume on the next page.

**I can think of a few ways to achieve this (below) but they all feel like hacks. Is there something native I can use?**

Possible options:

- Track a $current_node counter and pass this to the handler constructor, each
  time we parse the file skip this many nodes before storing data.
- Similar to above but use tell/seek to skip on each new invocation
- Pre-process to split the file into multiple files of the correct size.

The first two are inefficient and the last is messy. Are there better options?

---

**Editing to explain more about the file structure and why alternatives don't work.**

Apart from some other data the bulk of the structure is as below.

```
<DETAILS>
    <DETAIL>
        <ITEM1>...</ITEM1>
        <ITEM2>...</ITEM2>
        ...
    </DETAIL>
    <DETAIL>
        <ITEM1>...</ITEM1>
        <ITEM2>...</ITEM2>
        ...
    </DETAIL>
    ...
</DETAILS>
```

For the file in question each `<DETAIL>` node is roughly 240 bytes in size, which isn't much but we have over 180,000 of them (this is one of the smaller files that fails to process). `LibXML` fails when it hits this structure since it attempts to parse it all into memory (we are limited to a 32-bit system and there are other significant structures in Perl's memory).

After updating to the latest version and some code tweaks, `XML::Twig` will parse the document, but I still have the same issue - is it possible to pause and resume later?

I don't control the entire logic flow, so when the main application is ready for the next page it calls my object to get it. I need to be able to output a chunk of data and wait for the next request. This could probably be handled by a `fork` but I'm not sure that should be required.

---

**Example showing program flow.**

This is a simplification (especially the while loop). The real program has a complex nested structure of document pages which contain multiple objects representing page elements. It is defined by using a web service call and is also data driven so we cannot hard code any assumptions for this.

I can't see how to fit a callback into this - processing must resume after the table to emit the remaining page elements, start a new page, and emitting the first few page elements of that new page before resuming the table.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $table = Table->new('details.xml');

my $table_finished = 0;
while (!$table_finished) {
    # emit some data e.g. page header
    # ...
    # emit the table - 2 data rows per page, for testing
    $table_finished = $table->partial_emit(2);
    # emit some data e.g. page footer
    # ...
}

exit;

package Table;

sub new {
    my ($class, $filename) = @_;

    my $self = {
        '_file' => $filename,
    };

    bless ($self, $class);

    my $sub_ref = $self->can('process_table_row');

    $self->{'_twig'} = XML::Twig->new( 
                twig_handlers => {
                    'DETAIL'    => sub {
                        $sub_ref->($self, @_),
                        },
                });     

    return $self;
}

sub partial_emit {
    my ($this, $rows) = @_;
    $this->{'_rows_emitted'} = 0;
    $this->{'_limit'} = $rows;
    $this->{'_finished'} = 1;

    # we want this to return after parsing part of the file if it is large
    $this->{'_twig'}->parsefile($this->{'_file'});

    # should be zero if we returned early
    return $this->{'_finished'};
}

sub process_table_row {
        my ($this, $twig, $elt) = @_;

        # increase row count
        $this->{'_rows_emitted'}++;

        # handle data - doesn't matter what it does here
        print $elt->text, "\n";

        # we've done as many as we want - how to stop processing and return to main loop?
        if ($this->{'_rows_emitted'} >= $this->{'_limit'}) {
            print "Limit reached\n";
            # Ideally we'd set this, tell Twig to stop for a while, and carry on, but in my test script this causes an infinite loop
            #$this->{'_finished'} = 0;
        }       
}

1;
```

---

And another edit... it seems after tweaking my search I stumbled across what I wanted this whole time. `XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental` has a `parse_more` routine that does exactly what I need. I'll need to wait a few days to test on the full data set but a brief test as below works.

The `Table` class can do this:

```
$self->{'_parser'} = XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental->new( Handler => MyHandler->new($self) );
```

where `MyHandler` is a simple `XML::SAX` style handler which now has access to the `Table`.

A call to `Table::partial_emit` will do something like this:

```
my $buf;
my $bytes_to_read = 50; # small for testing
while (read($this->{'_fh'}, $buf, $bytes_to_read)) {
    $this->{'_parser'}->parse_more($buf);
    # MyHandler will increment this based on the number of rows (DETAIL nodes) encountered
    if ($this->{'_rows_emitted'} >= $rows) {
        $this->{'_finished'} = 0;
        last;
    }
}
```

The above probably has some bugs in edge cases but it works fine for my test. I will need to stress test it properly later and see if it's production ready.

Comment: Please clarify *"is it possible to pause and resume later?"*. `XML::Twig` will wait for the callback that you have specified to return. If *later* means a few microseconds then there is no problem, but if it could be years then you have a different design problem. The same applies to your *BIG BROTHER* main application. You haven't described anything that prevents you from waiting for a decade or two before responding to *IT*.

Comment: @Borodin pause is the incorrect word I shouldn't have used it. Yielding control would be more accurate. We want twig to return after a specific number of nodes, normal processing to resume, then the object owning the twig is called again later and it should resume reading where it left off. I will attempt to add a simplified example later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I came across a very useful old thread which details exactly what I need.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=420383

I can use `XML::Parser::ExpatNB` for the behaviour I need. `XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental` will wrap this up into a SAX interface if necessary but I don't think I'll bother.

Sample code is below. It performs well enough (faster than `XML::Twig`) so I'll be using this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Parser::Expat;

my $parser = XML::Parser::ExpatNB->new();

$parser->setHandlers('Start' => \&start_element,
                     'End'   => \&end_element,
                     'Char'  => \&char_data);

my $read_size = 64 * 1024; # test to find optimal size
my $file_name = '../details.xml';
my $buf;

open(my $fh, '<', $file_name) or die $!;
binmode($fh);

my $bytes_read;
while ( $bytes_read = read($fh, $buf, $read_size) ) {
    $parser->parse_more($buf);
}
$parser->parse_done();
die "Error: $!" unless defined($bytes_read);
close($fh);
```

I have omitted the handlers, they are typical for this kind of approach (`$_[0]` is the `XML::Parser::ExpatNB` object which includes the current context, `$_[1]` is the data e.g. node name or character data).

`XML::LibXML::Reader` also works as shown below, I didn't entirely understand the interface earlier. It is slower on my machine though, and the node handling required is a bit more complex (e.g. CDATA is not automatically returned as text), so I will avoid it for now.

```
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => $file_name) or die $!;
while ($reader->read) {
    processNode($reader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module was designed to perform well in situations like this.

Its subtitle is *“A perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode”*.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention - I like Twig's style and did try it on this particular document but I gave up waiting after an hour, while SAX finished in a minute or two for a full parse (without constructing the table). I will review tomorrow to ensure we have the latest version and see what went wrong. I would prefer SAX if possible since it seems so lightweight.

Comment: @NickP: You may not have set up `XML::Twig` properly. You should set a callback (a twig handler) for the XML element that you want to process as a *unit*, and make sure to `flush` the tree at the end of the callback, otherwise the entire tree is being held in memory and `XML::Twig` is no better than `XML::LibXML` or any other module that builds a whole tree from the XML data.

Comment: Beyond what Borodin said, which I concur with, XML::Twig also comes with a tool called `xml_split`. It offers a few convenient ways of splitting a big file in several smaller ones (by depth, number of nodes or size of the split files). This may help you if you choose to go this way.

Comment: I should also mention that XML::LibXML::Reader may also be a good option.

Comment: @Borodin: XML::Twig works now that I've reviewed my script but I run into the same issue of being able to stop/resume.

Comment: @mirod: I've added some more details. LibXML fails due to reading the entire structure. xml_split may work but would prefer to avoid creating multiple files during processing (I mentioned this as an option so am considering it if necessary though).

Comment: @NickP: Please show your `XML::Twig` code and describe how it doesn't fulfil your requirements. I think it should be a new question. `XML::LibXML` also provides a streaming option, but I'm unfamiliar with it myself.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not really sure what to show. It is just a basic handler for DETAIL that stores data in a structure. The issue is that when we have processed enough that we risk running out of memory (e.g. 5,000 records are stored) we need Twig to yield control to the caller of parse_file such that normal execution can resume. At a later point we return to the object owning the Twig, and need XML::Twig to resume processing from where it left off.

Comment: @NickP: What I am trying to resolve is whether your design is right. I don't see anything in what you've written that precludes a simple callback on every occurrence of a `DETAIL` element.

Comment: @Borodin I've added a simplified example. The design as it stands is mostly data driven, via the data XML and a SOAP response. A generic output engine has been written to cater for this, containing document pages containing a collection of objects which produce output. My task is to produce a simple object that emits as much of the table as will fit on each page, and advise the caller whether more remains for the next page. Upon the next call I will produce more of the table. The general design is too complex to show here.

Comment: @NickP: I think you're looking for a module that satisfies your design rather than designing your solution around an available module. You seem to be expecting a *pull* interface which, to my knowledge, is provided only by [`XML::LibXML::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Reader). I have never used [`XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::SAX::Expat::Incremental), but I worry about its `parse_start`/`parse_more`/`parse_done` interface because SAX is inherently a *push* interface, and these calls just pretend otherwise.

Comment: In what I have read of your requirement, I don't see any reason to avoid a *push* interface. It is, after all, what you get with the standard Perl `while (<$fh>) { ... }` loop, and from your experience with that you will know that it is simple to bundle multiple records into pages. However, I suspect that, by now, you have committed yourself to your own solution, so I wish you well with that. Please remember to add your own solution here and mark it as accepted. And a very Happy Christmas!

Comment: @Borodin thanks for your efforts, I have posted 2 examples that will work for me. My original question was not well-phrased but essentially our plugin architecture cannot change as it provides useful encapsulation of data and behaviour. The parent just needs to tell each plugin how much to emit, and the plugin manages everything internally. This is why we need a solution that can partially process XML on each call, as parsing the entire file into memory causes a crash. Hope you had a Happy Christmas too :)